# How to get src tag from image?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get the src property from an `img` tag.
The problem's that I get no `src` of the image, but an empty string. Instead if I remove the `//img/@src` I see the content of `a` tag (image). What's the problem?
I saw other similar question, but no solution provided working for me.

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="container left">    
     <div class="logo">
        <a href="/teams/japan/japan/1348/">
        <img src="http://cache.images.core.optasports.com/soccer/teams/150x150/1348.png" alt="Giappone">
       </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

this is my code:

```
var shieldHomeContainer = nodeCollection.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='container left']//div[@class='logo']//a//img/@src");
```

Comment: node collection contains a list of node of grabbed html page, the current node contain the html that I posted above @Thomas you could try anyway my code put the html in a string and paste my code so you can see that not working the grab for src image property

Comment: are you able to get the other tags from other lines?

Comment: @SimonPrice I'm able to get other tags content, but I've only this issue with img tag. Seems infact that I cannot extract the link of the image source.

Comment: can you share more of your code  specifically how you are reading in the html so that I can try and reproduce and find an answer for you

Comment: Next time, please try to provide compilable source code like the one in my answer. Then it's easier to set up a test for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this

```
var shieldHomeContainer = nodeCollection.SelectSingleNode("//img").Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't select an attribute directly. You need to select an element and then call `GetAttributeValue()`.

```
var h=new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
h.LoadHtml(@"
<div class=""clearfix"">
  <div class=""container left"">    
     <div class=""logo"">
        <a href = ""/teams/japan/japan/1348/"" >
        <img src=""something"" alt=""Giappone"">
       </a>
     </div>
</div>");
var img = h.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(
 "//div[@class='container left']//div[@class='logo']//a//img");
Debug.WriteLine(img.GetAttributeValue("src","nothing"));
```

If you want to make sure that the element has that attribute, use `img[@src]`.